# Is there a way to submit several like inputs as a List from a Form?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, json, forms

I have a form that has 10 text input fields for first names, and 10 text input fields for last names.  Only the first is required, so I expect 1-10 variables from both first and last name fields.

Right now I'm pulling out all 20 from the query String and ignoring the empty ones.

QUESTION: is there a way I can pass these to the server as a JSON String, and then iterate through them server side?

I'm using Django templates, jQuery (POSTing in ajax) and Python on a Google App Engine server.

HTML:

```
<label>First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="fname-1" id="fname-1" /><br/>
<label>Last Name</label>
<input type="text" name="lname-1" id="lname-1" /><br/>

<label>First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="fname-2" id="fname-2" /><br/>
<label>Last Name</label>
<input type="text" name="lname-2" id="lname-2" /><br/>

<label>First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="fname-3" id="fname-3" /><br/>
<label>Last Name</label>
<input type="text" name="lname-3" id="lname-3" /><br/>
....
```

jQuery:

```
var fname_1 = $("input#fname-1").val();
var fname_2 = $("input#fname-2").val();
var fname_3 = $("input#fname-3").val();
var fname_4 = $("input#fname-4").val();
var lname_1 = $("input#lname-1").val();
var lname_2 = $("input#lname-2").val();
var lname_3 = $("input#lname-3").val();
var lname_4 = $("input#lname-4").val();
....

    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "/foo/",  
        data: {"fname_1":fname_1,"fname_2":fname_2,
                   "fname_3":fname_3,"fname_4":fname_4,
                   "lname_1":lname_1,"lname_2":lname_2,
                   "lname_3":lname_3,"lname_4":lname_4},  
        dataType: "json",
    ...
```

Py:

```
fname_1 = self.request.get('fname_1')
fname_2 = self.request.get('fname_2')
fname_2 = self.request.get('fname_3')
fname_2 = self.request.get('fname_4')
lname_1 = self.request.get('lname_1')
lname_2 = self.request.get('lname_2')
lname_2 = self.request.get('lname_3')
lname_2 = self.request.get('lname_4')

#do stuff, check for missing properties, create new Object with data ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the jQuery [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method. It'll do all the work for you and send all the form values to the server where you can iterate through them. So you could change your code to:

```
var data = $("form").serialize();
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "/foo/",  
    data: data,  
    dataType: "json",
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `serialize()`. Try:

```
var myData = $("#formId").serialize();

$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "/foo/",  
    data: myData,  
    dataType: "json",
...
```